# Proper use of na.omit()

Tags: r, function, na

I am a new to R and I have run into a problem trying to omit rows in a particular column (variable) which contain NAs. I am using the na.omit() function.

After uploading 12 datasets and combining them into one, I created a new variable which calculates the difference between the end and start times a given bike was used by a customer of a shared bike company. I called this new variable "length_time".  After making certain this variable was a numeric, I proceeded to create a new database in which the observations where the length_time is either negative (when the bikes were being repaired) or NA are removed.  While my code removes the negative entries, it will not remove the NA entries for the column in question (code below).

Any assistance would be most appreciated. (And please explain any problems to me in Kindergarden fashion ;)) .

Here is my code:

```
##Adding Ride Length Variable
#(My original, combined dataset is called "all_trips")

all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$ended_at, all_trips$started_at)

##Converting Ride Length Variable into a Numeric

all_trips$ride_length <- as.numeric(all_trips$ride_length)

##Deleting Rows Where Ride Length is Negative and/or NA
#(And creating a new dataset called "all_trips_v2")

all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0)] %>%
  na.omit(all_trips$ride_length)
```

Comment: Personally, I don't use magrittr pipes but my understanding is that is should just be `%>%  na.omit` without the parenthesis.

Comment: Just a missing comma. Try `all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[(BOOLEAN EXPRESSION), ] %>% na.omit`. Without the `,` after your filtering expression you are not telling R which rows you want.

Comment: Thank you both.  I think I got it.  What do you think of my solution?  I just wanted to filter out NAs from one variable, viz., trip_length: 

##Deleting Rows Where Ride Length is Negative

`all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0),]`

##Deleting Rows Where Ride Length is NA

`all_trips_v3 <- all_trips_v2 %>%
  drop_na(ride_length)`

Answer (score 0):

```
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0)] %>%
  na.omit(all_trips$ride_length)
```

it should be `all_trips$ride_length <= 0` I think